# Valores de array estão zerados ao exibir

Tags: c, programação-estruturada

Galera, tenho esse código simples em C e gostaria de saber o motivo de eu estar tentando exibir o array total e o valor que está me retornando é 0, caso eu coloque esse printf dentro do primeiro while os valores são impressos certos, mas como faço para imprimir foraw Sou iniciante no C.

O restante do código está totalmente funcional.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 30

int main() {

int produto[N], i=0, cont=0;
double preco[N], total[N], totalCompras=0;


printf("Digite quantos produtos deseja cadastrar: ");
scanf("%d", &i);


while (cont<i) {
    printf("Digite a quantidade vendida do %dº produto: ", (cont+1));
    scanf("%d", &produto[i]);

    printf("Digite o preco da unidade do %dº produto: ", (cont+1));
    scanf("%lf", &preco[i]);

    total[i] = (produto[i]*preco[i]);
    totalCompras += total[i];

    cont++;
}
int j=0;
while(j<i) {
    printf("\n Total de vendas do produto: %0.2lf\n", total[j]);
    j++;
}

printf("\nTotal das compras: %0.2lf\n", totalCompras);


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja bem, no loop `while` que você programou a variavel `cont` irá iterar até que ela seja menor que a variável `i`( que é a variavel que recebe o número de cadastro de produtos ), só que o índice do array que você está usando para inserir os valores e para fazer o calculo esta sendo `i` onde deveria ser `cont`, então ficaria mais ou menos assim.

```
    ...
    while (cont<i) {
        printf("Digite a quantidade vendida do %dº produto: ", (cont+1));
        scanf("%d", &produto[cont]);

        printf("Digite o preco da unidade do %dº produto: ", (cont+1));
        scanf("%lf", &preco[cont]);

        total[cont] = (produto[cont]*preco[cont]);
        totalCompras += total[cont];

        cont++;
    }
    ...
```

Outro detalhe a se notar não que tenha relação com a sua pergunta mas que talvez possa lhe ajudar é o uso do `#define`, você poderia usar `const unsigned int N = 30`, ai ficaria assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    const unsigned int N = 30;
    ...
}
```

E também o uso de uma `struct` que iria aninhar os arrays `produto`, `preco` e `total`, ficando mais ou menos assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct venda{ //struct que aninha produto, preco e total
    unsigned int quantidade;
    double valor_unitario;
    double sub_total;
};

int main() {

const unsigned int N = 30; //não estou utilizando #define
unsigned int i=0, cont=0;
double totalCompras=0;

struct venda vendas[N]; //Criando um array de structs

printf("Digite quantos produtos deseja cadastrar: ");
scanf("%d", &i);


while ( cont < i ) {
    printf("Digite a quantidade vendida do %dº produto: ", ( cont + 1 ) );
    scanf("%d", &vendas[ cont ].quantidade ); //populando a variavel quantidade do meu array vendas no indice cont

    printf("Digite o preco da unidade do %dº produto: ", ( cont + 1 ) );
    scanf("%lf", &vendas[ cont ].valor_unitario );//populando a variavel valor_unitario do meu array vendas no indice cont

    vendas[ cont ].sub_total = ( vendas[ cont ].quantidade * vendas[ cont ].valor_unitario);//populando a variavel sub_total do meu array vendas no indice cont
    totalCompras += vendas[cont].sub_total;

    cont++;
}

cont = 0;
while( cont < i ) {
    printf("\n Total de vendas do produto %i: %0.2lf\n", cont + 1, vendas[ cont ].sub_total );
    cont++;
}

printf("\nTotal das compras: %0.2lf\n", totalCompras );


}
```

Comment: Funcionou! Vou implementar as dicas, obrigado.